# AJAX handler not found in found when use plugin in static pages

Tags: octobercms

[image]

This is my plugin file system. I add the plugin by creating the snippet of the plugin then add it to the static page in. It add successfully but when i submit the for by using **data-request** it gives error of AJAX Handler not found. I add the jquery in script and also user
{% framework extras %}

{% framework %}
but it gives error.

The code in **default.htm** file is

```
*<form name="plan-form" data-request="onSendEmail" data-request-validate
    data-request-flash class="row ttm-quote-form clearfix">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" data-validate-error>
            <p data-message></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 form-group mt-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control bg-white" required name="name" placeholder="Name">
            <span data-validate-for="name"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 form-group mt-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control bg-white" required name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
            <span data-validate-for="phone"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 form-group mt-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control bg-white" required name="email" placeholder="Email">
            <span data-validate-for="email"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 form-group mt-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control bg-white" required name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
            <span data-validate-for="subject"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 form-group mt-2">
            <textarea class="form-control bg-white" name="message" required placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            <span data-validate-for="message"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 form-group mt-2">
            <select name="plan" id="" class="form-control bg-white" required>
                <option value="Free">Free</option>
                <option value="Standard">Standard</option>
                <option value="Premium">Premium</option>
            </select>
            <span data-validate-for="plan"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 text-left">
            <button type="submit" data-attach-loading class="oc-loader ttm-btn ttm-btn-size-md ttm-btn-bgcolor-skincolor">Send</button>
        </div>

    </form>*

And the code of **PlanForm.php** file is

*<?php
    namespace Virtuenetz\Plan\Components;
    // use Virtuenetz\Plan\Models\Plan;
    use Cms\Classes\ComponentBase;
    use Input;
    use Mail;
    use Validator;
    use ValidationException;
    use Flash;
    class PlanForm extends ComponentBase{
        public function componentDetails()
        {
            return [
                'name' => 'Plan Form',
                'description' => 'Simple Plan Form'
            ];

        }

        public function onSendEmail(){

            $data = post();

            $name = post('name');
            $phone = post('phone');
            $email = post('email');
            $subject = post('subject');
            $msg = post('message');

            $rules = [
                'name' => 'required',
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'subject' => 'required',
                'message' => 'required',
                'plan' => 'required',
            ];

            $validation = Validator::make($data, $rules);

            if ($validation->fails()) {
                throw new ValidationException($validation);
            }

            print_r($data);die;
            $var  = ['name' => Input::get('name'), 'email' => Input::get('email'),
            'phone' => Input::get('phone'), 'subject' => Input::get('subject'),
            'message' => Input::get('message'), 'plan' => Input::get('plan')];

            Mail::send('virtuenetz.plan::mail.message', $var,function($message){
                $message->to(Input::get('email'),'Admin Person');
                $message->subject(Input::get('subject'));
            });

            Flash::success('Jobs done!');
        }
    }
?>`enter code here`
*
```

Comment: can you please check once that you added that component to your page correctly?

Comment: I use this component in the static pages by creating snippets. I create a form in the plugin and registered the form in the Plugin.php file of the Component and the form added successfully in the static page but when i call the function with data-request it gives handler not found error. I also add the jquery and [% framework extra %]. Is it possible to the plugins in the static pages with snippets?

Comment: @MehtabAhmed I updated my answer showing you proof that you can do what you want to do. You need to post all of your code or link to your plugin files and maybe I can solve it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sadly It's the actual limitation of static pages, you can not use AJAX handlers on them.

So, either try to use the normal page OR make a custom/manual ajax request using JQUERY to the component's handler.

> OR better add that component to `Layout` page

> Ref => https://octobercms.com/blog/post/introducing-snippets

[image]

if you have any doubt please comment.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I create a component and use it by creating its snippet. When adding a snippet it's necessary to add the component name to the default layout page.

Answer (score 0):

What does your snippet code look like?

So I just tested this on my own static page. I have managed to make successful Ajax requests with a plugin using snippets and static pages. I do not have a component field in the layout. I also for clarity tested this with both V2 and V1 of OctoberCMS. [Here is a test page to see it in action.](https://dev.branmuffinstudios.com/testrequest)

I think the most important thing is to make sure you are using the correct name reference. So in my opinion if your registered component is `chatBoi` then you should make the snippet the same `chatBoi`. However using `{{ __SELF__ }}` should make this not a factor. Also all of my javascript requests `$.request()` are working fine.

**Plugin PHP:**

```
<?php namespace Branmuffin\Chatboi;

use System\Classes\PluginBase;

class Plugin extends PluginBase
{
    public function registerComponents()
    {
        return [
            'BranMuffin\Chatboi\Components\ChatBoi' => 'chatBoi'
        ];
    }

    public function registerPageSnippets()
    {
        return [
           'BranMuffin\Chatboi\Components\ChatBoi' => 'chatboi',
           'BranMuffin\Chatboi\Components\TestRequest' => 'testRequest'
        ];
    }

    public function registerSettings()
    {
    }
}
```

**Component PHP:**

```
<? namespace Branmuffin\Chatboi\Components;

use October\Rain\Support\Collection;
use CMS\Classes\ComponentBase;
use Input as Inputs;
use Mail;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Flash;
use Session;
use Crypt;
use str;
use Redirect;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class TestRequest extends ComponentBase
{

    public function componentDetails() {
        return [
            'name' => 'TestRequest',
            'description' => "Test Request"
        ];
    }

    public function onTestRequest() {
        $count = 1;    
        if (Session::has('count')) {
            $count = 1 + Session::get('count');
            Session::put('count', $count);
        } else {
            Session::put('count', $count);
        }
        $this->page['count'] = 'success '. $count;
        return 'success '. $count;
    }

//END COMPONENT }
```

**Twig Markup:**

```
<h2>Test Request</h2>

<form name="plan-form" data-request="onTestRequest" data-request-validate
    data-request-flash data-request-update="'@count': '#result'">
    <p>
        <code style="word-break: break-all;">
            &lt;form name="plan-form" data-request="onTestRequest" data-request-validate
        data-request-flash class="row ttm-quote-form clearfix"&gt;
                &lt;button type="submit"&gt;Test Request&lt;/button&gt;
            &lt;/form&gt;
        </code>
    </p>
    <button type="submit">Test Request</button>
    <p id="result">
        {% partial '@count' %}
    </p>
</form>
```

**Static Page OctoberCMS V2:**

[image]

**Network Proof Of Request:**

[image]

**Image Of Layout Field:**

[image]

---

This information below this line still applies to creating successful components.

Add `{{ __SELF__ }}::onSendEmail`

[Here are the docs.](https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/handlers#calling-handlers)

If two components register the same handler name, it is advised to prefix the handler with the component short name or alias. If a component uses an alias of mycomponent the handler can be targeted with mycomponent::onName.

`<button data-request="mycomponent::onSubmitContactForm">Go</button>`

You may want to use the **SELF** reference variable instead of the hard coded alias in case the user changes the component alias used on the page.

`<form data-request="{{ __SELF__ }}::onCalculate" data-request-update="'{{ __SELF__ }}::calcresult': '#result'">`

Comment: I used this but it's not working. I used this in hard code or with SELF reference or with exact component name.

Comment: @MehtabAhmed You can get it to work. Tested with a plugin I have been developing and created a quick test plugin. Check your layout. Make sure {% frameworks %} is after jquery and themes aren't effecting OctoberCMS front end framework.

Comment: I did all this but the issue was that I cannot add the component in the default layout page which I used for the static page, I only add the component I the static page but the default layout page which is used by this static page we should also add a component in this page. 

I create a custom plugin then create its snippet because the plugin does not access the static pages so I create a snippet and then add it to the static page.

Comment: Thank you for your response and for helping me.

Comment: @MehtabAhmed Sounds like you got this sorted out though I don't think its the correct answer.

You do **NOT** have to add any component to the page or the layout. You only need the snippet for static pages and it will work fine.